# How to get values of m2m fields before saving in database?

Tags: python, django, signals, m2m

I want to get values of m2m fields when I changi this fields in my model.
I tried to use m2m_changed signal, but I get None values in action, pk_set,instance.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=UserProfile)
def m_2_m_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    action = kwargs.pop('action', None)
    pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    if action == "pre_save":
        for f_old in instance._meta.many_to_many:
            mm_old = sorted(getattr(instance, f_old.name).values_list('pk', flat=True))
        return mm_old
```